# Xamarin Cross Platform Picker not binding correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin Cross Platform apps

I am trying to bind a Picker ItemSource to a List and display one property, with out success! My reference has been [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource)

Please can some one advise where my error is, my View or Xmal please (or probably both)

The List  is a List of StdGrades defined as

```
namespace FitRestults_Dev1
{
    class StdGrade 
    {
        public string Gradelbl
        { get; set; }
        public string Grade
        { get; set; }

        public static List<StdGrade> Grades()
        {
            List<StdGrade> GradesList = new List<StdGrade>(){
                new StdGrade(){ Gradelbl="10th Gup (White belt)", Grade="G10"},
                new StdGrade(){ Gradelbl="9th Gup (Organge belt)", Grade="G9"},
                new StdGrade(){ Gradelbl="8th Gup (Organge belt 1 tag)", Grade="G8"},
               ... };

                return GradesList;

        }  

            public List<StdGrade> GradesList => Grades();


            public static string GetGrade(string Input)
        {
            List<StdGrade> GradesList = Grades();
            var result = (from r in GradesList where r.Gradelbl == Input select r).First();

            return result.Grade;


        }

    }
```

For the Content page I have defined a simple view as

```
    namespace FitRestults_Dev1
{
    class AddStudentView 
    {
        List<StdGrade> _GradeList;

            public List<StdGrade> GradeList

        { get => _GradeList;
            set
            {
                _GradeList = StdGrade.Grades();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My content page xmal is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FitRestults_Dev1.AddStudent"
             xmlns:src="clr-namespace:FitRestults_Dev1"
             >
     <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <src:AddStudentView/>
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid>
                …
                <Picker x:Name="GradePicker" Title="Select a Grade" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" MinimumWidthRequest="100" FontSize="12"
                     ItemsSource="GradeList" SelectedIndex="0" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Gradelbl}">
                </Picker>
            </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing the itemsSource the incorrect way it should be a binding

```
  ItemsSource={Binding GradeList}
```

Also Stop using `Generic.List` for binding, MVVM  with  Xamarin Forms should have `ObservableCollections` as it inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`

Comment: Thank  you blast I missed that and a good point about collections. I would use that in wpf. I was following the docs example. I will test later and mark it up

Comment: No I think I have my basic syntax wrong for my page wrong. Please see question {link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739066/back-to-basics-xamarin-forms-binding)

Comment: What do you want me to see in the link brother